# Marker don't orient properly at the end of SVG path with D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a visualization where the lines between 2 nodes are connected via path using d3.svg.diagonal as shown in http://www.isi.edu/~shubhamg/d3-test-6.html

As it can be seen, the markers do not orient properly at the end of the SVG path (by markers I mean the arrows at the end of paths) Any suggestions to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EliranMalka Pretty sure Op just means the arrows should be in-line, like you would normally draw an arrow.

Comment: By 'properly' I mean that the triangles (markers) at the end of the path are not at correct angle. In this example: http://bl.ocks.org/1153292 the markers orient properly according to the angle at the end of path.

Comment: well, you've got the source code right there. investigate it a little. or at least point us at the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the Force Directed Graph example called "[Mobile Patents](http://bl.ocks.org/1153292)".  I believe it's a small example that shows exactly how to do this.

I hope it helps.

Frank

Comment: I started working on this visualization using that example only. The links are not Bezier curves in the "Mobile Patents" example.

Comment: That example works on Chrome and breaks on Firefox. The arrow head is drawn on the opposite side of the circle from the path.